# Charts.js how to fix the height with more than 50 horizontal bars

Tags: css, chart.js

How can I fix my chart, the problem is that I have many horizontal bars, so the chart breaks.

```js
var barOptions_stacked = {
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false
    },
    hover :{
        animationDuration:0
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true,
                fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
                fontSize:11
            },
            scaleLabel:{
                display:false
            },
            gridLines: {
            }, 
            stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false,
                color: "#fff",
                zeroLineColor: "#fff",
                zeroLineWidth: 0
            },
            ticks: {
                fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
                fontSize:11
            },
            stacked: true
        }]
    },
    legend:{
        display:false
    },

};

var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ["2014", "2013", "2012", "2011","2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011"],
        
        datasets: [{
            data: [727, 589, 537, 543, 574],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,103,126,1)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50,90,100,1)"
        }]
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

  <div class="graph_container">
    <canvas id="Chart1"></canvas>
  </div>
```

I tried to use a scroll, but it didn't work well. Because the size of the bars are too small and is impossible to read

What would be the best solution for this ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fix it, I used this solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/jbfLuo53/

The solution was to control de height size in the js file and set it using `Jquery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your **canvas** in a div and make div scrollable.
Then increase the height of canvas.

For make scrollable:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work.